# kubectl command running in VM but not running in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, devops

I have installed jenkins on the ubuntu server. I have copied the config file to my home .kube/config folder. When I am running "kubectl get pods" command directly in the VM, it's running fine. But when I ran it in the jenkins pipeline the command is failing. I have tried it with providing --kubeconfig $PATHFORKUBECONFIG file.

Can anyone please help me with my query?

Comment: How do you run jenkins?

Comment: @Thomas I have installed Jenkins via the apt install command

Comment: Is it running in the same VM as you run kubectl for testing? Please provide the error mesages / command output.

Comment: Yes Thomas.. Its running in the same VM .. when i am running the kubectl get pods directly on the vm its running fine. But the jenkins job is giving me the error

Comment: + kubectl get pods --kubeconfig /home/kunal8817/.kube/config
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable aws-iam-authenticator not found

It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.

To learn more about this feature, consult the documentation available at:
      https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Comment: The aws-iam authenticator is already installed in the vm.

Comment: Where is the iam executable installed on the machine?

Comment: Its installed in both root and non-root user

Comment: Can you provide the path?

Comment: I have installed it using these steps https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html.
I guess it's at my home path.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed jenkins as a different user with custom `PATH` environment. Access to the cluster uses the amazon iam-helper binary, which is not on the `PATH` for the jenkins user.

Either add the location of the binary to your `PATH` (of jenkins user) or put the binary to a location which is on the path, for example `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: The binary aws-iam-authenticator must be in the PATH

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue @KJ1791 ? I am facing similar issue in GKE.

Comment: I tried that as well but it didn't work. I have then installed tomcat and then deployed the Jenkins.war. Its running fine there..